# Spinner row touchable region is only text

Tags: android, android-spinner, selecteditem

In my Android app, I have a spinner in the ActionbarSherlock:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_left_spinner"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

It populates just fine, but only the text portion of the spinner row, not the blank portion, is touchable and responds to the `onItemSelected` event.

I can't seem to figure out how to span the entire width of the apinner item to make it touchable.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I had a `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent` set in the spinner XML...